# Loading a script with the same variables than other and override

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I`m using 2 different javascript files for two different languages, 1 file call lang.en.js that is in english and the other is lang.es.js, both files contains the same variables for example:
lang.es.js

```
var messages: {
    settings: {
        settings: "Opciones",
        language: "Idioma"
    }
}
```

lang.en.js

```
var messages: {
    settings: {
        settings: "Settings",
        language: "Language"
    }
}
```

So at first of my phonegap application i load only one of the files, i want to give an option to the user so he can change the language during the execution of the app, how can i override the other file or reload the entire app?.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XHR to load the file as JSON and parse it. Something like this:

```
    var messages = {};
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "lang.en.json", true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        console.log("state = " + request.readyState);
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
                messages = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    request.send();
```

and change you .js file to be a .json:

```
{
    settings: {
        settings: "Settings",
        language: "Language"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have to figure it out other problems and this lose some priority. The next week i will test this and i tell you how it goes. ;).